# Pandas correlation error - decimal and float type mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

This problem has [been raised here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503835/error-with-corr-function-in-pandas), but has not been answered.  I am providing more details in this thread, hoping that gets the juices flowing.

I have a pandas dataframe `master_frame` that contains timeseries data:

```
     SUBMIT_DATE   CRUX_VOL        CRUX_RATE
0     2016-02-01   76.38733173161  0.02832710529
1     2016-01-31   76.68984699154  0.02720243998
2     2016-01-30   75.59094829615  0.02720243998
3     2016-01-29   75.91758975956  0.02720243998
4     2016-01-28   76.31809997200  0.02671927211
...          ...   ...            ...
```

I want the correlation between `CRUX_VOL` and `CRUX_RATE` columns.  Both are decimal type:

```
ln[3]: print type(master_frame["CRUX_VOL"][0]), type(master_frame["CRUX_RATE"][0])
out[3]: <class 'decimal.Decimal'> <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

When I use the corr function, I get a nasty error that relates to the type of the inputs.

```
print master_frame['CRUX_VOL'].corr(master_frame['CRUX_RATE'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:/Programming/VolPathReport/VolPath.py", line 52, in <module>
    print master_frame['CRUX_VOL'].corr(master_frame['CRUX_RATE'])
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1312, in corr
    min_periods=min_periods)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 47, in _f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 644, in nancorr
    return f(a, b)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 652, in _pearson
    return np.corrcoef(a, b)[0, 1]
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2145, in corrcoef
    c = cov(x, y, rowvar)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2065, in cov
    avg, w_sum = average(X, axis=1, weights=w, returned=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 599, in average
    scl = np.multiply(avg, 0) + scl
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

I've messed with the types and can't get this thing to work.  Help me, o wizards of the internet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of the error message points to

```
np.multiply(avg, 0) + scl
```

as the cause for

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

I don't think `numpy` has a `Decimal` type, so `np.multiply` returns `float`, which then doesn't collaborate with `Decimal` when using the `+` operator. Since `pandas` relies on `numpy`, it's probably best to convert the `DataFrame` to `float` `dtype` using

```
master_frame.loc[:, ['CRUX_VOL', 'CRUX_RATE']].astype(float)
```

or

```
master_frame.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Comment: `master_frame["CRUX_VOL"] = master_frame["CRUX_VOL"].astype(float)` &
`master_frame["CRUX_RATE"] = master_frame["CRUX_RATE"].astype(float)`
do the trick.  Thank you

Comment: why `.loc` vs what I have written?

Comment: `master_frame.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` is deprecated, the alternative to use is `pd.to_numeric`: `master_frame["CRUX_VOL"] = pd.to_numeric(master_frame["CRUX_VOL"])`
Sadly there appears to be no version for `DataFrame` itself